# Constraint update not working properly on iPhone 5, same iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am having some trouble with one constraint.

I have a `wrapperView` at the bottom of my screen, and it has constraints, one of them is Top Constraint to Top Layout Guide.

That view has two views,

1. `minView`, which is visible when wrapper view is at the bottom, and
2. `maxView` view, which is visible when I change constraint to Top Layout Guide.

When I click on that view, `constraint.constant` is changed to lower number to slide it from bottom to the top. Everything is working on `iPhone 6` and above, but on iPhone 5 it just hides `minView` view of that wrapper view and shows `maxView` view which is behind buttons, and not on whole screen.

**This is the code:**

```
minViewHeight.constant = 0
wrapperViewTopGuide.constant = 122
self.wrapperViewTopGuide.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) {
     self.minView.alpha = 0
     self.maxView.alpha = 1
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     self.wrapperView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Does anyone know what's the catch?

Comment: Add your UI images so that we can understand your issue more accurately

Comment: Thank you for seeing this, I've managed to done it with activating and creating and deactivating constraints